# Direct Update not working in windows phone devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Direct Update For Windows phone 8 devices is not working while it is working fine with iOS any idea ?

Enviornment : Mobile First 7.1.0
Windows phone 8 Nokia

Application Descriptor Editor->WIndows phone 8 -> Security Test: Default 
while App Authenticity Config is set up Basic.Below is authenticationConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<staticResources>
    <resource id="receiveSMS" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/receiveSMS*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>
</staticResources>

<securityTests>
<customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1"/>
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SubscribeServlet"/>
    </customSecurityTest>

    <customSecurityTest name="LDAPSecurityTest">
       <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="LDAPRealm"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
 <customSecurityTest name="winfoneSecurityTest">
  <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
  <test mode="perSession" realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1"/>
  <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" step="1"/>
  <test isInternalDeviceID="true" realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm"    step="2"/>
</customSecurityTest>
</securityTests>
<realms>
 <realm loginModule="rejectAll" name="SubscribeServlet">
  <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
  </realm>
</realms>
<loginModules><!-- cannot share confidential info --></loginModules>
</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

Comment: Are you sure your windows device connected with mfp server?

Comment: Please add your authenticationConfig.xml to the question

Comment: Also, your exact MFP version.

Comment: Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160129-1923 , WAR version 7.1.0.00.20160206-1558

Comment: I do not see authenticity configured in your authenticationConfig.xml; where is it?

Comment: a) Which of these securitytests are applied to the Windows Phone 8 environment in application-descriptor?
b) You are referring to Windows Phone 8 environment (Silverlight) and not the WindowsPhone that gets added when you chose Windows 8 universal ?

Comment: We are using basic app authenticity and in application descriptor we are not using security test right now but we tried by using winfoneSecurityTest which was also not working

Comment: @MichealSmith, any updates to this question?